# TFX complains upstream components were not run in interactive mode

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

Please find notebook here
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Qb-uv5JtyZhMl1BEVHplZmfULgV-BN45?usp=sharing

The upstream components (transformed examples in this caser were executed succesfully with context.run() however trainer still complains that it was not done

The notebook was training fine with TFX 0.22 but getting this error in TFX 0.23

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-a501b7646f34> in <module>()
----> 1 context.run(trainer)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tfx/components/base/base_driver.py in resolve_input_artifacts(self, input_dict, exec_properties, driver_args, pipeline_info)
    158                 'components must first be run with '
    159                 '`interactive_context.run(component)` before their outputs can '
--> 160                 'be used in downstream components.') % (artifact, name))
    161         result[name] = artifacts
    162       else:

ValueError: Unresolved input channel Artifact(artifact: custom_properties {
  key: "name"
  value {
    string_value: "transformed_examples"
  }
}
custom_properties {
  key: "pipeline_name"
  value {
    string_value: "tfx-segmentation"
  }
}
custom_properties {
  key: "producer_component"
  value {
    string_value: "Transform"
  }
}
, artifact_type: name: "Examples"
properties {
  key: "span"
  value: INT
}
properties {
  key: "split_names"
  value: STRING
}
properties {
  key: "version"
  value: INT
}
) for input 'examples' was passed in interactive mode. When running in interactive mode, upstream components must first be run with `interactive_context.run(component)` before their outputs can be used in downstream components.
```

Comment: Can you try it with TFX Version 0.24.1 and see how it goes? Thanks!